# How can you yank/print the match from a regular expression and only the match of a regular expression?

Tags: regex, unix, vim

I have a whole bunch of variable names that I need to move around between migration files, views, locale files and so forth.

I don't want to re-type all of these, nor do I want to copy, paste and trim because I have done too much of that.

I have been trying to pull these out through a regular expression but every time I try to do so, the entire line is printed instead of just the variable name I want that begin with ':' and end with '\s' as in: :name, :email, :home_phone, etc.

How can I get these to just extract out what I want?

I've been trying to do this in vim with:

```
      :%s/:.*\s/y
```

Here's the input file:

```
      <%= f.input  :name %>
      <%= f.input  :email %>
      <%= f.input  :home_phone %>
      <%= f.input  :cell_phone %>
      <%= f.input  :other_phones %>

      <%= f.input  :last_position_candidate_id %>
      <%= f.input  :last_position_title %>
      <%= f.input  :last_position_company_id %>
      <%= f.input  :last_position_start_date %>
      <%= f.input  :last_position_salary %>
      <%= f.input  :last_position_medical_insurance %>
      <%= f.input  :last_position_christmas_bonus %>
      <%= f.input  :last_position_annual_bonus %>
      <%= f.input  :last_position_vehicle %>
      <%= f.input  :last_position_other_benefits %>

      <%= f.input  :conversational_english %>
      <%= f.input  :written_english %>
      <%= f.input  :vehicle %>
```

This is what I would like to get:

```
              :name 
      :email 
      :home_phone 
      :cell_phone 
      :other_phones 
      :last_position_candidate_id 
      :last_position_title 
      :last_position_company_id 
      :last_position_start_date 
      :last_position_salary 
      :last_position_medical_insurance 
      :last_position_christmas_bonus 
      :last_position_annual_bonus 
      :last_position_vehicle 
      :last_position_other_benefits 
      :conversational_english 
      :written_english 
      :vehicle
```

Comment: You're using imprecise terminology: yanking means copying to a register (leaving the text intact), but you're showing attempts at substituting, which means actually changing what's in the buffer (cutting away the stuff you don't want). Both can actually be combined (but that's an advanced level). It all depends on what you want to do with the text.

Comment: I want to leave this text intact, but I want to reuse a large part of that text in a new file. I could yank the part that I want into a VIM register and switch to a new file or copy the file and extract that part of the text that I want to reuse. It is imprecise because I could do it either way. Yanking is preferable because it involves less steps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unless you do this all the time, the clone & substitute is easier; you already have an answer for that. Yank is only better when you want to automate the whole process via a mapping, but it's way more complex, and therefore less suited to typing from memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%s/.*\(:\w\+\)\s.*/\1/
```

See http://vimregex.com/#backreferences for more information.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid re-typing, it might be sufficient to

```
:set iskeyword+=:
```

open the source file in Vim, and use the built-in insert-mode completion (e.g. `:last_` followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>) in another buffer.